# I am facing this issue many times and i am unable to solve it

Tags: android

[image]

I need the solution and why this is occur

Comment: Next time you ask a question, instead of "this issue", write what issue it is, how it happened, what have you tried to solve it etc. Don't post pictures of text, include the original text in your question, and we won't consider your question more urgent than the ones of other people, so please don't ask anything like that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because some of the dependency libraries that you're using have elements which do not have "android:exported" attribute.

You need to do this:

- Lower the version in your gradle to 30 and sync and build.
- Go to your AndroidManifest.xml file and click on "Merged Manifest".
- Find items that don't have "android:exported" attribute.
- Then add them to your AndroidManifest.xml file in this way.

```
<activity
    android:name="SomeActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="merge"
    tools:replace="android:exported" />
```

Now you can increase your version to the latest.

If that doesn't help, you may need to remove "enableJetifier" from your gradle.properties file.